# How to make 2 drives be 1 volume?

Tags: 16.04, gparted, mate

I have a 500GB drive and 20.0GB drive and i want to do a little experiment and see if i can make them be 1  : HOW I  DO THAT ON Gparted ?

Comment: Easy: RAID 0, but that increases your chances of data loss, and you can't do that in GParted

Answer (score 0):

You can't make GParted directly combine two physical drives into one volume.

You can, however, use `mount` to mount an entire volume in place of any directory, making (for instance) `/home/[user]/` be an entire separate hard disk.  You can also do this with appropriate entries in `/etc/fstab`, so that it occurs automatically on every startup.